# What does the output of file "/bin/cp" mean

Tags: command-line, files, cp

The output of `file /bin/cp` is :

```
/bin/cp: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=ea4510e2ea94e09894383430c178b21df065faac, stripped
```

what does it mean ?

Comment: Have you started by reading the [manual page for `file`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/file) , to understand its basic function and output?

Comment: That's the `copy command` used to copy files in Linux, and `file /bin/cp` is used to describe the file type. Run `man file` in terminal to see what `file` command does.

Answer (score 3):

Let's take it apart piece by piece:

- `/bin/cp` name of the program you're passing to `file` command. In this case , it is `cp`, the program for coppying files and folders.
- `ELF 64-bit LSB shared object`: an external program can use this program's functionality. See my related question [Executables vs Shared objects](https://askubuntu.com/q/690631/295286)
- `x86-64` - compiled for 64-bit OS
- `version 1 (SYSV)` - uses Unix System V standard for [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface). [See Linux file command: what does SYSV imply?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9470867/3701431)
- `dynamically linked` - uses functionality of other programs/libraries. See kos's answer on my question.(Link #1)
- `interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` - this is the program that will load the executable and all the libraries necessary for the program to work. See  [PatchELF](https://nixos.org/patchelf.html) for simple explanation in the first pargraph. See also [Dynamic Linker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_linker) on Wikipedia
- `for GNU/Linux 2.6.32` - the `glibc` library used to compile that program was targeted at Linux kernel 2.6.32. See [linux command “file” shows “for GNU/Linux 2.6.24”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12236159/3701431)
- `BuildID[sha1]=ea4510e2ea94e09894383430c178b21df065faac` - sha1 hashsum for the build session, most useful for developers to debug their program and see which particular version of their code was used. See [What does BuildID SHA1 mean?](https://askubuntu.com/q/139770/295286)
- `stripped` - contains no debugging information. See [What are stripped and not-stripped executables in Unix?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/2969/85039)

Comment: How can you tell who owns `cp`? And who's its creator? What command line convention it follows? Like did the macOS create the command? or is it Unix based? or does it follow POSIX or Unix?

Comment: Actually `man cp` tells me: "STANDARDS
     The cp command is expected to be IEEE Std 1003.2 (“POSIX.2”) compatible.

HISTORY
     A cp command appeared in Version 1 AT&T UNIX."